# Trigger an event using window.location.hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I'm trying to trigger an event by clicking an external link from an email using the jquery/javascript window.location.hash. Unfortunately the app is built with angular and has a hash in the url initially `https://www.electricstudio.ph/#/`

I even tried adding the hash manually but the functionality doesn't seem to trigger. `https://www.electricstudio.ph/#/`

```
function slideSignUp() {
    $('.header-form-container.signup').addClass('active');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.location.hash == '#sign-up') {
        console.log('PING');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This usually works for me:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function () {
    hashUrl = window.location.hash;
    if (hashUrl == "#sign-up") {
         console.log('PING');
    }
});
```